# Use Vue on top of an existing static website to add filtering functionality

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an existing **static website** with a list (a `<ul>` with `<li>`s) for which I cannot modify the original HTML. Each item has several key-value pairs inside, marked with `<span>`s and `class`es.

Only if the device supports Javascript, I want to add filtering capabilities.

I have managed to dynamically add *with jQuery* a filter box with the different values of the different fields in the items, but reading the existing data, keeping track of the filter status and showing/hiding items accordingly is way too complicated, compared to what it would be with Vue.

Is there a way to "inject" Vue and "bind" the existing list to Vue, so that 1) the data is available directly inside Vue and 2) when the filter is modified by the user, then the `<li>`s are hidden/shown automatically?

I am open to alternative solutions, keeping in mind that the list of items has to be shown even if Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally bind Vue to a basic HTML template, it's even the default example on the official doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering

```html
<div id="app">
  [...content when JS is disabled]
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Then, you can either create the whole thing in Vue (will not be available wo/ JS tho) or get the various values with a [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) and you should be done to make any kind of logic then !

You could maybe even pass the variable directly into the scope, since it will be defined in the upper scope. Never tried myself tho.

Comment: Hi! The first part, no. I need to have the page visible even with JS inactive. The $refs, I haven’t had the time to try. Don’t worry, once I try I will let you know and accept the answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: This can be an addition to the HTML markup. Sorry if it was not clear. Alright, thanks !